# Thai national to Spain from UK

Tags: visas, spain, uk-residents, thai-citizens

My Thai girlfriend has a six month visa to visit the Uk and we would like to go on holiday to Spain for two weeks while she is here.Is this possible without too much expense and documentation required for visas etc.

Comment: She will need a Schengen visa.  It will be easiest if she applies at the consulate responsible for her place of residence, but she cannot apply more than 90 days (or three months, I do not remember the precise requirement) before she plans to enter Spain, so it will be easiest if you plan the Spain trip for the early part of her stay in the UK.

Comment: She has already arrived here last week,so we are looking at a holiday in possibly the middle of August. Would it be better to go in person to the Spanish consulate to ask or request an entry visa.

Comment: If she is already in the UK then you probably cannot go to Spain until *after*  three months have elapsed, because you likely have no reason to ask for an exception to the rule that she should apply in her place of residence.  Even then, for tourism, it is unlikely that the consulate would grant an exception in any case. But I do not know how strictly the Spanish observe that rule.  It may be worth it to you to try.  Finally, if your relationship is long-standing and "durable" then you may be able to apply for a visa under freedom of movement, in which case the restrictions are not applicable.

Comment: Thankyou. we will apply in person at the Spanish consulate

Comment: In general, consulates have only been taking in-person applications from EU family (freedom of movement) applicants, though again I don't know Spain's practices. If you've been together for a while, definitely start with that.  Most other applicants have to go through third-party processing firms. This could make it harder for you to get to talk with someone who knows anything.  Good luck, and please let us know what happens by posting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The Embassy of Spain in London may not entertain a visa application as it requires it be done where she legally resides. You can try and, in advance, [complete the application](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/ContenidoReutilizable/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Documents/visadoSchengen_EN.pdf). While the expense is modest, it takes some effort to assemble the documentation: passport and previous visas, travel insurance, purpose of visit, flight and hotel reservations, and proof of means of subsistence. Before you do, you might enquire about the feasibility of applying through the consulate.

Consulate General of Spain in London
20 Draycott Place, London SW3 2RZ
Tel: 020 7589 8989
Fax: 020 7581 7888 
cog.londres@maec.es